# Woocommerce how to remove coupon code box programmatically

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I wonder if you can help? I'm trying to get this to work.
I want to only show the coupon box when the price is more than 19.99 AND its not product id 455821
I can't get this to work. Would you be able to give me any ideas why?

Thanks
Kevin

```
// START Remove coupon box when price is less than 19.99
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupons_enabled','hide_coupon_field_on_cart' );
function hide_coupon_field_on_cart( $enabled ) {
    global $product;
//  $id = $product->get_id();
    $product_id = 455821;

    $price = "19.95";
    $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
        foreach ( $cart as $id => $cart_item ) {
        //  $prodid = $cart_item[ 'data' ]->$product->get_id();
        if( ($cart_item[ 'data' ]->get_price() <= $price) || ( $cart_item[ 'data' ]->$product->get_id() != $product_id ) ) {
            return false; // dont remove it 
        }
    }   


    return $enabled;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
// START Remove coupon box when price is less than 19.99
function hide_coupon_field_on_cart( $enabled ) {
    // settings
    $not_product_id = 455821;
    $min_price = 19.99;

    // Get cart object
    $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();

    foreach ( $cart as $cart_item ) {
        // product id
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

        // Price
        $price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();

        if ( $product_id == $not_product_id && $price < $min_price ) {
            $enabled = false;
        }
    }

    // Cart total <= 0
    if ( WC()->cart->get_total() <= 0 ) {
        $enabled = false;
    }

    return $enabled;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupons_enabled','hide_coupon_field_on_cart' );
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I mean the product price as in my case there can only ever be one item in the cart at any one time.
It would also be very handy to not show the coupon box at all if the price of the basket is 0. We have a free subscription level.